# Process multiple files in jq

Tags: json, jq

Imagine I have two files as below:

file1:

```
[   
  "id1",
  "id2"
]
```

file2:

```
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name1"
  },
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name2"
  },
  {
    "id": "id3",
    "name": "name3"
  },
  {
    "id": "id5",
    "name": "name5"
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "name": "name6"
  }
]
```

I want to find those entries in file2 that their id exist in file1, in the example above the expected output should be like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name1"
  },
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name2"
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "name": "name6"
  }
]
```

How can I achieve it with jq.

Comment: Easy approach: Reduce your first input into a dict of the form `{"id1": true, "id2": true}`, then use a `select()` expression on the second to filter for ids that exist in that dict.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the answer, I would appreciate if you could provide a sample, my main problem is that I can not use the output of the first process(dict in your approach) in the second command in bash, how can I pass this dict and use it in the second command. There are some examples for passing simple string value, but I do not know how to pass and use this dict.

Comment: Why two different commands at all? You can pass multiple inputs to one copy of jq; using the `-n` argument tells it not to consume them until you do so deliberately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get better/more succinct answers, but this seems to work.  *Slurp* both files into an array, use `file1.json` contents as a filter to `reduce` `file2.json`.

```
jq --slurp '.[0] as $filt | reduce .[1][] as $ref ([]; if IN($ref.id; $filt[]) then . + [$ref] else . end)' file1.json file2.json
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/k6QU3QheCar).

If the file sizes are large, this might be better since it doesn't *slurp*.

```
jq --null-input 'input as $filt | reduce inputs[] as $ref ([]; if IN($ref.id; $filt[]) then . + [$ref] else . end)' file1.json file2.json
```

Try this on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/jKZa2epkuql).

Both output:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name1"
  },
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name2"
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "name": "name6"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

With both inputs already being arrays, there's no need to `--slurp`. Also, as there are exactly two inputs, there's also no need to call on `--null-input`, just use `input` for the second one. For example, using the inputs in reversed order:

```bash
jq 'input as $ids | map(select(IN(.id; $ids[])))' file2.json file1.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name1"
  },
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name2"
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "name": "name6"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_Ce4054_22V)